# PHP echoes empty post array, even when fed params

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, post, amazon-ec2, http-post

I am very new to php and am trying to create a REST API for my mobile backend. I'm using aws EC2 and have stored the following php file on my EC2 instance. But anyway, here is the code:

```
<?php include "FILE WITH DB INFO"; ?>
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL" . mysqli_connect_error();

$database = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_DATABASE);

$user_username = $_POST['username'];
$user_name = $_POST['name'];
$user_email = $_POST['email'];

echo "BEFORE --- ";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "AFTER";

if (strlen($user_username) || strlen($user_name) || strlen($user_email)) {
    AddUser($connection, $user_username, $user_name, $user_email);
}


function AddUser($connection, $username, $name, $email) {
    $u = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
    $n = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);

   $query = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('username', 'name', 'email') VALUES ('$u', '$n', '$e');";
    if(!mysqli_query($connection, $query)) echo("ERROR ADDING USER DATA");
}

function VerifyUsersTable($connection, $dbName) {
    if(!TableExists("users", $connection, $dbName))
    {
            $query = "CREATE TABLE 'users' (
            'name' varchar(255),
            'username' varchar(255),
            'email' varchar(255),
            PRIMARY KEY ('username')
            )";

   if(!mysqli_query($connection, $query)) echo("ERROR CREATING TABLE");
    }
}
echo "MADE IT";
?>
```

My issue is that the `var_dump($_POST);` returns an empty array that looks like this: `array(0) { }`. This occurs even when I pass it three parameters like this: 
params:
`?username=TestUser&name=TestName&email=TestEmail`

actual request used:
`http://my_ec2_instance/Test.php?username=TestUser&name=TestName&email=TestEmail`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: picture of postman screen
[POSTMAN SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmjwz.png)

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com please look at what happend to little-bobby tables and learn about SQL injections. Your code is really unsave (real_escape_string won't help you that much...) - use prepared statements. Visit the website to learn more about it and how to use them correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This request:

```
http://my_ec2_instance/Test.php?username=TestUser&name=TestName&email=TestEmail
```

is a `GET` request, not `POST`.

Access it by: `$_GET['name']`

Comment: How can I change it to a post request?

Comment: Depends how you send this request.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Its a HTML form? Curl?

Comment: Ummm I'm not really sure what those are... Would it make sense if I said it was from a MySQL database?

Comment: No, how this request URL is called?

Comment: I don't really know, I just put it in my web browser (I also used POSTMAN, and it didn't work either). The php file is in a folder called html, so I would assume I should be using html to make the request. I don't really know how to do that though.

Comment: In postman you have to change request type to `POST` and add this variables from your URL to body of this request. In HTML there should be a `<form>` tag, where you need to change method to post by adding: `<form method="post">`

Comment: Even when I use postman with the request type as `POST`, it still echoes out an empty array.

Comment: But dont pass this variables on URL. In Postman you have tab called Body, where you should put your data. Or just change `var_dump($_POST);` to `var_dump($_GET);` in your PHP code.

Comment: When I pass the variables in the form-data part in postman, it works. But it prints them out in a very weird way: `WebKitFormBoundaryfRuQaD0Mrq4YdrlB Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=> string(259) ""username" lolol`. Also when I try to `echo` each of the parameters individually `echo($_POST['name'])`, it doesn't work. Why can't I access them individually?

Comment: Ok, added at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Change `form-data` to `x-www-form-urlencoded`, should be fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use $_GET[] . And to print all $_GET varaiables try:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `$_REQUEST`.
Just see this [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

And access like it,

```
$_REQUEST['username'], $_REQUEST['name'], $_REQUEST['email']
```